# GeoServer inactive functions

Tags: geoserver, windows-11

I have installed GeoServer 2.23.1 (Windows installer) and I am using it on localhost. Whenever I try to change something like contact details, add a new store, GeoServer doesn't apply any changes. Pressing the save button returns to the previous text. In the new store tab, every option is 'disabled', which means that when you hit 'postgis/shapepile/...' it doesn't launch any expected windows to fill out.

Configuration:
Win 11
GeoServer 2.23.1

Thanks for help/suggestions.
Java 11

Comment: Check that the user running GeoServer has permission to write to the data directory that you have set. Then you need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I'm not sure why but there is something wrong with my Chrome browser . I opened Geoserver in MS Edge and everything works fine.